# Creating personal customized set of brushes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

Actually there are two questions here.

1. Creating personal customized  new set of old brushes, where I want
   to put different brushes from different sets (like 2 from assorted,
   2 from basic etc.) in one set.
2. Creating personal customized  set of new brushes, how can I
   create my own brushes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is how to create new customized brush set from old brushes :**

go to `Edit > Preset Manager > select brush from dropdown` first load all the brushes which you want to use in your set (like all from assorted,all from basic )  You'll see all the brush now select one by one which you want in your brush set, `select brushes (ctrl+click for multi) > save this set >` 
again go to `preset manager > load set` which you have saved just now.

I attached a screen shot to make this process easy and clear to you, please follow the same (view image in new browser for clarity)

[image]

**This is how to create new brush :**

First create any shape/drawing/art or anything of which you want to make brush, than again go to `Edit > Define brush preset > Ok`  by this you can create as many as brushes you want and if you want to make set of such new brushes do as first answer says...

this is your brush :) 
 i have attached a screenshot to make this clear...

[image]

Tutorial for your reference :

- [How to Create a Custom Photoshop Brush Set Tutorial](http://bloomwebdesign.net/myblog/2011/09/02/how-to-create-a-custom-photoshop-brush-set-tutorial/)
- [Tutorial: How to Make a Photoshop Brush Set](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/design/how-to-make-a-photoshop-brush-set/)

Hope this will help....

Answer (score 1):

Creating brushes is really easy :

1: create your brush

2: put a selection round it

3: go to Edit : Define Brush Preset

It will be added to bottom of you brushes .

Comment: this is how to create a single brush, i think op wants to know how to create set of brush